# Redirect file to ls

Tags: file, shell, redirect, ls

Is it possible to redirect output of a file to ls. 
Example: file has a `/` in it and I want to direct that to ls to get the content of the `/` directory. When I try `ls < file` this does not work

Comment: Interesting answer  you accepted :-) Did you really try running `ls "$(cat your_file)"`? What shell are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `xargs` or command substitution to achieve this.

1. ### Use xargs

   The key is knowledge of the [xargs command](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-bsd-xargs-construct-argument-lists-utility/).

   If you have a list of files in a file called `files_to_change`, you
   can print them with the following one liner:

   ```
   cat files_to_change | xargs ls
   ```
2. ### Use command substitution

   An alternate method is to use [command substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html). This works
   the same as above.

   Two different one-liners, using different syntax:

   ```
   ls `cat files_to_change`
   ls $(cat files_to_change)
   ```

---

It won't matter if they are files or directories, and you can run any command on them.

If the contents of `file_to_change` was:

```
/usr/bin/
/bin/
```

`cat files_to_change | xargs ls` and `ls $(cat files_to_change)` would be equivalent to running:

```
$ ls /usr/bin/
$ ls /bin/
```

The output on the console should be what you want.

Comment: `xargs` really doesn't add anything here. All you need is command substitution.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `xargs`. This very useful utility runs a command with arguments which are passed in as input:

```
cat myfile | xargs ls
```

Answer (score 0):

`ls 'cat your_file'`

beware, the ' is the <kbd>altGr</kbd>+<kbd>7</kbd> char (but used for formatting here !)